# I made a transfer of 0.101, but only 0.09308715 arrived

Tags: wallet-transfer

Where did the missing ethereum go? I payed 0.00088378 in fees, making the total transfer 0.10188378.

So,
Wallet 1: -0.10188378
Fee: 0.00088378
Wallet 2: +0.09308715
Where did the remaining 0.00791285 ETH ~ $1.50USD go?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know without looking at the transaction.

You could trace the interaction on [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io) by looking up the transaction with the wallet 1 address in the search box. Just follow each step in the transaction forward.

If the transaction was over to an exchange, like Bittrex, then there may be fees associated with moving the ethereum over to the exchange wallet via their smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought the Ether from exchanges they probably took a cut. I know Coinbase does.